# microphone not starting after one iteration in sphinx

Tags: cmusphinx, sphinx4

I am using CMU sphinx library, but after successfully running one iteration, this error appears "Can't open microphone line with format PCM_SIGNED 16000.0 Hz, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, big-endian not supported." Cannot start microphone. When run on eclipse in ubuntu 12.10, code works fine for all iterations. Why is this error appearing when using eclipse in Windows 7 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have something like this in your config xml file:

```
<component name="microphone"
            type="edu.cmu.sphinx.frontend.util.Microphone">
    <property name="closeBetweenUtterances" value="false"/>
</component>
```

try to change "false" too "true" and rebuild.

Comment: Thankyou Nikolay it made my code work the way i wanted, but after every iteration it prints on the console "set to null", and hence my code is not using the string(from voice input) of one iteration in next. Pls help.