# Can't access microphone while running Dialog demo in sphinx4 5prealpha

Tags: java, cmusphinx, sphinx4

I am trying to run the dialog demo of sphinx 4 pre aplha but it gives errors.

I am creating a live speech application.

I imported the project using maven and followed this guide on stack overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25963020/2653162

The error says about issues regarding the 16 khz and channel being mono. So clearly its about the sampling stuff. And is also says about microphone.

I looked on how change the microphone settings to 16 khz and 16 bit but there is no such option in windows 7

:[image: Only Options available in win 7]

The thing is that the HelloWorld and dialog demo worked fine in sphinx4 1.06 beta but after I tried the latest release it gives following  errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException: line with format PCM_SIGNED 16000.0 Hz, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, little-endian not supported.
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.api.Microphone.<init>(Microphone.java:38)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.api.SpeechSourceProvider.getMicrophone(SpeechSourceProvider.java:18)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.api.LiveSpeechRecognizer.<init>(LiveSpeechRecognizer.java:34)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.demo.dialog.Dialog.main(Dialog.java:145)
Caused by: javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException: line with format PCM_SIGNED 16000.0 Hz, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, little-endian not supported.
    at com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectDL.implOpen(DirectAudioDevice.java:513)
    at com.sun.media.sound.AbstractDataLine.open(AbstractDataLine.java:121)
    at com.sun.media.sound.AbstractDataLine.open(AbstractDataLine.java:413)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.api.Microphone.<init>(Microphone.java:36)
    ... 3 more
```

Cant figure out what to do to resolve the issue.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev sound card is Conexant SmartAudio HD

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry, this is a bug in sphinx4 that recognizer doesn't release the resource properly and Windows java doesn't allow to open the microphone the second time.

Comment: Relevant issue in our tracker https://sourceforge.net/p/cmusphinx/bugs/412/

Comment: I'll try to fix it in a coming days

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev The demo did not work even once .....

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev Bro please read my entire question… the issue is also about 16khz and 16bit and mono channel u removed that for the edited question… inform me if u want me to add that again

Comment: No, it is not related to 16khz, we have many reports on this issue before. It is about exclusive access. Note that microphone was successfully opened first time but failed second time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73325/discussion-between-abc-and-nikolay-shmyrev).

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev U suggested that my question might have an answer but the links in that answer have nothing....so should I go back to sphinx4 1.06 beta instead of 5preaplha ?

Comment: Just wait over weekend, we'll fix it

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev Any solution to the pronblem?

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev should I switch back to using sphinx4 instead of 5prealpha?

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev this is still broken. Do you expect patch expected any time soon? Thanks! edit: Since swapping grammars requires having multiple recognizer, this is a a blocker. Is the only thing required for a fix exposing flush()?

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev still not fixed it seems

Comment: any hack/workaround for this for now?

Comment: i tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15750556/microphone-not-starting-after-one-iteration-in-sphinx?rq=1) solution too but pointing to api/microphone but it now errors cant find digits.grxml resource where before it could.

Answer (score 5):

If you modify `SpeechSourceProvider` to return a constant microphone reference, it won't try to create multiple microphone references, which is the source of the issue.

```
public class SpeechSourceProvider {
    private static final Microphone mic = new Microphone(16000, 16, true, false);

    Microphone getMicrophone() {
        return mic;
    }
}
```

The problem here is that you don't want multiple threads trying to access a single resource, but for the demo, the recognizers are stopped and started as needed so that they aren't all competing for the microphone.

Comment: This worked for me too. As of 2019 I just cloned the github repo and faced the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

As Nickolay explains in the source forge forum ([here](http://sourceforge.net/p/cmusphinx/discussion/sphinx4/thread/b31b5b35/)) the microphone resource needs to be released by the recognizer currently using it for another recognizer to be able to use the microphone. While the API is being fixed, I made the following changes to certain classes in the sphinx API as a temporary workaround. This is probably not the best solution, guess until a better solution is proposed, this will work.

---

I created a class named `MicrophoneExtention` with the same source code as the `Microphone` class, and added the following methods:

```
    public void closeLine(){
        line.close();
    }
```

Similarly a `LiveSpeechRecognizerExtention` class with the source code of `LiveSpeechRecognizer` class, and made the following changes:

- use the MicrohphoneExtention class I defined:
  `private final MicroPhoneExtention microphone;`
- inside the constructor,
  `microphone =new  MicrophoneExtention(16000, 16, true, false);`
- And add the following methods:

```
    public void closeRecognitionLine(){
        microphone.closeLine();
    }
```

Finally I edited the main method of the `DialogDemo`.

```
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.setAcousticModelPath(ACOUSTIC_MODEL);
    configuration.setDictionaryPath(DICTIONARY_PATH);
    configuration.setGrammarPath(GRAMMAR_PATH);
    configuration.setUseGrammar(true);
```

`configuration.setGrammarName("dialog");
    LiveSpeechRecognizerExtention recognizer =
    new LiveSpeechRecognizerExtention(configuration);

    Recognizer.startRecognition(true);
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Choose menu item:");
        System.out.println("Example: go to the bank account");
        System.out.println("Example: exit the program");
        System.out.println("Example: weather forecast");
        System.out.println("Example: digits\n");

        String utterance = recognizer.getResult().getHypothesis();

        if (utterance.startsWith("exit"))
            break;

        if (utterance.equals("digits")) {
            recognizer.stopRecognition();
            recognizer.closeRecognitionLine();
            configuration.setGrammarName("digits.grxml");
            recognizer=new LiveSpeechRecognizerExtention(configuration);
            recognizeDigits(recognizer);
            recognizer.closeRecognitionLine();
            configuration.setGrammarName("dialog");
            recognizer=new LiveSpeechRecognizerExtention(configuration);
            recognizer.startRecognition(true);
        }

        if (utterance.equals("bank account")) {
            recognizer.stopRecognition();
            recognizerBankAccount(Recognizer);
            recognizer.startRecognition(true);
        }

        if (utterance.endsWith("weather forecast")) {
            recognizer.stopRecognition();
            recognizer.closeRecognitionLine();
            configuration.setUseGrammar(false);
            configuration.setLanguageModelPath(LANGUAGE_MODEL);
            recognizer=new LiveSpeechRecognizerExtention(configuration);
            recognizeWeather(recognizer);
            recognizer.closeRecognitionLine();
            configuration.setUseGrammar(true);
            configuration.setGrammarName("dialog");
            recognizer=new LiveSpeechRecognizerExtention(configuration);
            recognizer.startRecognition(true);
        }
    }

    Recognizer.stopRecognition();`

and obviously the method signatures in the `DialogDemo` needs changing...
hope this helps...
and on a final note, I am not sure if what I did is exactly legal to start with. If i am doing something wrong, please be kind enough to point out my mistakes :D

Comment: I followed your modifications, when I run now I am getting this error: 
"java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected state READY actual state DEALLOCATED
 at edu.cmu.sphinx.recognizer.Recognizer.checkState(Recognizer.java:134)"

Comment: I am not sure where the problem could have occurred, mine works just fine, what is on the call stack? If i am reading this right, that exception gets thrown by the recognizer's decoder, not the line.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected state READY actual state DEALLOCATED
 at edu.cmu.sphinx.recognizer.Recognizer.checkState(Recognizer.java:134)
 at edu.cmu.sphinx.recognizer.Recognizer.recognize(Recognizer.java:103)
 at edu.cmu.sphinx.recognizer.Recognizer.recognize(Recognizer.java:122)
 at edu.cmu.sphinx.api.AbstractSpeechRecognizer.getResult(AbstractSpeechRecognizer.java:63)
 at edu.cmu.sphinx.demo.dialog.DialogDemo.main(DialogDemo.java:153)

Comment: this is the console output I got

Comment: Make sure the order of the statements are correct. 
1.stop recognition
2.close line
3.reassign recognizer
4.start recognition.
.........

as i said, this works for me just fine..

Comment: Hmm.... copied your code as it is... modified as you listed out... still getting that issue.

Comment: String utterance = recognizer.getResult().getHypothesis();

Comment: From what i have learnt, the `startRecognition()` method allocates the resources in the `recognizer`, and sets the `state` of the recognizer to `READY` from `DEALLOCATED`. when the `getResult()` method is called, it checks if the recognizer resources have been allocated by checking the `state`, and throws the exception you got if not in the correct state. So i am guessing your problem should be in the `startRecognition()` method of your `LiveSpeechRecognizerExtention`

Answer (score 0):

The answer of aetherwalker worked for me - in more detail I overwrote the following files with my own implementations where I only changed the used SpeechSourceProvider:

**First one is the AbstractSpeechRecognizer:**

```
public class MaxAbstractSpeechRecognizer {
protected final Context context;
protected final Recognizer recognizer;

protected ClusteredDensityFileData clusters;

protected final MaxSpeechSourceProvider speechSourceProvider;

/**
 * Constructs recognizer object using provided configuration.
 * @param configuration initial configuration
 * @throws IOException if IO went wrong
 */
public MaxAbstractSpeechRecognizer(Configuration configuration)
    throws IOException
{
    this(new Context(configuration));
}

protected MaxAbstractSpeechRecognizer(Context context) throws IOException {
    this.context = context;
    recognizer = context.getInstance(Recognizer.class);
    speechSourceProvider = new MaxSpeechSourceProvider();
} .......................
```

**Then the LiveSpeechRecognizer:**

```
public class MaxLiveSpeechRecognizer extends MaxAbstractSpeechRecognizer {

private final Microphone microphone;

/**
 * Constructs new live recognition object.
 *
 * @param configuration common configuration
 * @throws IOException if model IO went wrong
 */
public MaxLiveSpeechRecognizer(Configuration configuration) throws IOException
{
    super(configuration);
    microphone = speechSourceProvider.getMicrophone();
    context.getInstance(StreamDataSource.class)
        .setInputStream(microphone.getStream());
}......................
```

**And last but not least the SpeechSourceProvider:**

```
import edu.cmu.sphinx.api.Microphone;

public class MaxSpeechSourceProvider {

private static final Microphone mic = new Microphone(16000, 16, true, false);

Microphone getMicrophone() {
    return mic;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me with this change, the problem was as long as i was staying in a context of cmusphinx it was good the line can be reused many times. But if i begin to reuse the mic for another work (like recording) it was not available!
I see that the stream was open in Microphone class but never close!

So first I change in class `Microphone` the following attributes from static to dynamic :

```
private TargetDataLine line;
private InputStream inputStream;
```

After i change the method stopRecording for closing stream before line:

```
  /**
 * close the stream and line
 */
public void stopRecording() {

    if (inputStream != null )
        try {
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }

    line.stop();
```

}

And now with no more change (class SpeechSourceProvider is original), i can reuse alternatively mic for cmupsphinx and another recording task