# Sphinx LineUnavailableException

Tags: java, cmusphinx, sphinx4

Need help how to use Sphinx4 API correctly, i am read from this link : http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialsphinx4,but when i am run DialogDemo.java i am getting this error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException: line with format PCM_SIGNED 16000.0 Hz, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, little-endian not supported.
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.api.Microphone.<init>(Microphone.java:38)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.api.SpeechSourceProvider.getMicrophone(SpeechSourceProvider.java:18)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.api.LiveSpeechRecognizer.<init>(LiveSpeechRecognizer.java:35)
    at com.mycompany.spechrecognizer.DialogDemo.main(DialogDemo.java:143)
Caused by: javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException: line with format PCM_SIGNED 16000.0 Hz, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, little-endian not supported.
    at com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectDL.implOpen(DirectAudioDevice.java:513)
    at com.sun.media.sound.AbstractDataLine.open(AbstractDataLine.java:124)
    at com.sun.media.sound.AbstractDataLine.open(AbstractDataLine.java:416)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.api.Microphone.<init>(Microphone.java:36)
```

i have search in google how to fix it and the result :
[Can't access microphone while running Dialog demo in sphinx4 5prealpha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29121188/cant-access-microphone-while-running-dialog-demo-in-sphinx4-5prealpha)
and https://github.com/cmusphinx/sphinx4/issues/33
but i can not understand, can someone explain to me how to use sphinx API step by step correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is problem with sample DialogDemo.java. But other samples are working without any issue.

Answer (score -1):

I proposed a temporary work around for this problem until the API is fixed in the question [Can't access microphone while running Dialog demo in sphinx4 5prealpha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29121188/cant-access-microphone-while-running-dialog-demo-in-sphinx4-5prealpha/33189269#33189269)
what I had done is edited the code of the `Microphone` and `LiveSpeechRecognizer` classes,to be able to close the line opened to the microphone resource, so that another instance of the 'LiveSpeechRecognizer' can use the line.