# setting microphone format to Microsoft PCM, 16 bit, mono 8000/16000 Hz in Windows 10

Tags: windows, speech-recognition, frequency, microphone, sphinx4

I am making a speech recognition program in java using sphinx4. For that I require the output format of my microphone to be "Microsoft PCM, 16 bit, mono 16000/8000 Hz". I tried to change it from Microphone properties but it shows only 2 options: `2 channel, 16 bit, 44100 Hz(CD quality)` and `2 channel, 16 bit, 48000 Hz(DVD quality)`. How to add my required format. I don't want to convert the format of microphone audio. I want to change settings in my Windows 10.
Thanks

Comment: There is no such thing as "microphone format". Most likely you have some other problem, not the problem with a microphone. You need to provide the error message then.

Comment: I have searched google and many forums; through them I came to the conclusion that the problem is with its format. Following I have attached few lines of error message

Comment: Cepstrum component auto-configured as follows: autoCepstrum {MelFrequencyFilterBank, Denoise, DiscreteCosineTransform2, Lifter}
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException: line with format PCM_SIGNED 16000.0 Hz, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, little-endian not supported.
 at edu.cmu.sphinx.api.Microphone.<init>(Microphone.java:38)
 at edu.cmu.sphinx.api.SpeechSourceProvider.getMicrophone(SpeechSourceProvider.java:18) .........

Comment: Caused by: javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException: line with format PCM_SIGNED 16000.0 Hz, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, little-endian not supported.
 at com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectDL.implOpen(DirectAudioDevice.java:513)
 at com.sun.media.sound.AbstractDataLine.open(AbstractDataLine.java:121)
 at com.sun.media.sound.AbstractDataLine.open(AbstractDataLine.java:413)
 at edu.cmu.sphinx.api.Microphone.<init>(Microphone.java:36)
 ... 3 more

Comment: No, it is not a problem with the format, it is a problem with dialog demo on windows, a known one

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't access microphone while running Dialog demo in sphinx4 5prealpha](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29121188/cant-access-microphone-while-running-dialog-demo-in-sphinx4-5prealpha)

Comment: So, the problem is with creating  multiple recognizers. Okay, removed one recognizer but still there will remain the need to create a separate recognizer for language model. @Nikolay plz help me in this. And why API has not been updated in order to resolve this issue?

Comment: Just use a single recognizer, API is not reworked because it's a bit more complex problem that it seems.

Comment: okay! then plz update diolog demo... I am new, I am having difficulty in coding... thanx

Comment: Can u plz give me suggestion whether to use alpha or beta version of sphinx.. ?